# Laravel query builder: Select all fields except for a few

Tags: php, laravel-4

With the Laravel query builder, it is easy to select or alias fields with `->select()`.

How do I select all fields except for a few?
For example, I wish never to return the `id` of my record back to the front end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

If you don't mind still technically selecting them, you can *suppress* fields from Laravel's default array/JSON conversion:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'id', ...];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked it in the docs but it's not 100% clear. Does this mean that these fields won't be included in the return, but I hope that I can still use them for my queries?

Comment: Yes, you'll still have access to the data itself. This just hides it from things like `Response::json($user)` and `{{ $user }}`.