# Laravel, how to get the select::form selected value but not the id?

Tags: php, laravel

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get', 'class' => 'report-filter']) !!}
  {!!  Form::select('years', $available_year, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'--- Choose Year ---']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
$available_year = DB::table('purchases')
                    ->selectRaw('YEAR(purchase_date) as year')
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("YEAR(purchase_date)"))
                    ->orderBy('purchase_date')
                    ->pluck('year');
```

Everytime I try to send the request, the input request send the id of the year but I only wanted to get the value what inside the selection box. The image below shows the array of the select options with big red circle which i wanted to get.

[image]

For example, if I choose 2009, then what i wanted is the input request sends 2009 but not the id.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803079/laravel-query-builder-select-all-fields-except-for-a-few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lists`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_lists) to get the array with key/value pair

```
$available_year = DB::table('purchases')
    ->selectRaw('YEAR(purchase_date) as year')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("YEAR(purchase_date)"))
    ->orderBy('purchase_date')
    //->lists(your_value, your_key)
    ->lists('year', 'year'); //<- check this line
```

*Hope this helps!*

Answer (score 6):

Just do a `pluck('year', 'year')`. This will return an array with year as both index/key as well as  value of the returned array

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass array with [key/value or associative array](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field) to your select widget `Form::select` right now your keys are index no.s and values are years before passing to view transform your `$available_year` as

```
array(
    '2002' => '2002',
    '2003' => '2003'
    .....
)
```

Something like

```
$years = [];
foreach($available_year as $year){
    $years[$year] = $year;
}
```

Pass `$years` to view

```
 {!!  Form::select('years', $years, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'--- Choose Year ---']) !!}
```

[Drop-Down Lists](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

Comment: Instead of a loop, `array_combine($available_year, $available_year)`, would work nicely - https://3v4l.org/maVRg.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that is true, I just highlighted the issue, To make an associative array there can be many ways but i added a simple example